# sapply use in conjunction with dplyr's mutate_at

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I am trying to clean-up some data stored in multiple data frames using the same function repeatedly. I am trying in this example to leverage `mutate_at` from `dplyr` to convert to `Date` format all columns names which contain `'date'`.

I have a list of tables in my environment such as:

```
table_list <- c('table_1','table_2','table_3')
```

The objective for me is to overwrite each of the tables for which the name is listed in `table_list` with their corrected version. Instead I can only get the results stored in a large list.

I have so far created a basic function as follows:

```
fix_dates   <-  function(df_name){
  get(df_name) %>% 
     mutate_at(vars(contains('date')),
              funs(as.Date(.,
                    origin = "1899-12-30")
              ))
}
```

The `fix_dates()` function works perfectly fine if I feed it one element at a time with for example `fix_dates('table_1')`.

However if I use `sapply` such as `results <- sapply(table_list, fix_dates)` then I will find in `results` list all the tables from `table_list` at their respective indexes. However I would like to instead have `table_1 <- fix_dates('table_1')` instead for each of the elements of `table_list`

Is it possible to have sapply store the results ***in-place*** instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant way to do this, but I think this gets you where you want to go:

```
# use lapply to get a list with the transformed versions of the data frames
# named in table_list
new_tables <- lapply(table_list, function(x) {

   mutate_at(get(x), vars(contains("date")), funs(as.Date(., origin = "1899-12-30")))

})

# assign the original df names to the elements of that list
names(new_tables) <- table_list

# use list2env to put those list elements in the current environment, overwriting
# the ones that were there before
list2env(new_tables, envir = environment())
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting your answer as I was travelling. Your answer works perfectly. This `list2env()` function was unknown to me and it is very useful!